# REST / Web based authentication-as-a-service a possibility?

Tags: node.js, security, rest, express, authentication

I've developped a `REST` based service using `Express` and initially started implementing authentication myself. A simple username/password authentication where

- passwords are encrypted using BCrypt
- user info + hashed passwords are stored in a mongoDB
- password verification checks are done.
- authentication tokens (limited TTL) are generated / validated

I have some knowledge on Node.JS, but not nearly sufficient to make me feel comfortable about rolling out my own authentication (login/signup) mechanism.

For that reason I would like to replace my in-house mechanism with something else.

Something proven, extendable, pluggable and easy to use.

Given the amount of secure websites / REST APIs out there based on Node.JS, I'm sure there are out-of-the box solutions that people / companies have to offer that can get service implementors up and running very quickly, without having to worry about the security/user aspect.

I'm looking for an `even higher level of abstraction` than that of libraries like `passport` or `everyauth`. Something that provides out-of-the-box functionality, capable of fulfilling my requirements including :

- providing a login page / signup page / profile page
- different authentication modules (google,facebook,github,....)
- storing user info (+credentials if required) in a datastore (mongoDB).
- remember me
- forgot password / reset password

**So the question here is :**

- Are there `out-of-the-box` solutions like that available that offer a higher level of abstraction than passport/everyauth/... ?
- If any, would you recommend some of these out-the-box solutions ?
- Should I instead forget about the notion of `outsourcing my user authentication` and just start looking at passport and everyauth and start implementing my  requirements using those libraries ?
- Is it possible to focus on my business logic and not worry at all about any aspect regarding user authentication (writing login / signup pages , implementing forgot password / reset password flows, storing user info in the DB).

Comment: did you manage to come to an answer meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

The service API should largely live independent of your authentication mechanism, so I'd recommend starting this behind a simple password protected folder or some such. In my opinion it would be better to make sure you're API works and can gain traction. Meaning it'll be more a long term project. Nothing kills a project quicker than focusing on the painful stuff right out of the box.

As far as what service to use? It's non-trivial to setup security well. So for a small startup project, it's probably more cost-effective to integrate with another service. Might take a look at [Mozilla Persona](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/persona/). It's [built on Node](https://github.com/mozilla/browserid) and pretty straight forward.

If you do try to roll your own get some outside expertise, and **DON'T** do stupid stuff like use a hashing algorithm like SHA1 to store passwords. Instead use something like [bcrypt](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/). Then there are other things like, don't store server logs on the server they're created. Pipe out all logs elsewhere so if there's an intrusion you have a forensics trail back to what happened.

Comment: The API needs to be secured. I cannot "gain traction" on a non-secured API. If user-data is stolen/manipulated due to security issues I'll have other issues besides traction. I'm aware of the basics (hashing+salting, using SSL,....) . What is your experience with Mozilla Persona ?

Comment: I work at Mozilla so my opinion is going to be bias. It's still under development, but currently being used in production quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use https://stormpath.com/ . I'm looking for a free alternative myself..